# ruby code to determine self-describing numbers - problem with exit status

Tags: ruby, algorithm, exit, status

I've written the below code snippet in Ruby that reads a file (the file has some numbers on each line) The below code snippet determines if the number is a [self-describing number](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Self-describing_numbers) or not?

The snippet below is supposed to produce an output of 1 if the number is a self describing number or an output of 0 if the number is not a self describing number.

The code seems to work fine on my local machine but when i submit it to an online challenge that accepts these solutions to problems it is asking for an exit status of 0.

So, i added this line in the end:

```
system(exit 0)
```

But my solution to this problem is still failing just because of the exit status thing. A quick bash command as follows:

```
jasdeep:code$ ./self-def.rb myfile.txt ; echo $?
```

returns 0 at the end of the output - which means the program is infact exiting with exit status 0.

Am i doing something wrong with the exit status?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

filename = ARGV[0]

file = File.new(filename, "r")
while (line = file.gets)
  array = line.scan(/./)
  new_array = Array.new
  array.length.times do |var|
    new_array << array.count(var.to_s).to_s
  end
  if new_array.eql? array
    puts "1"
  else 
    puts "0"
  end
end
file.close
```

Comment: You don't need `system(exit 0)`, just `exit 0` will work.

Comment: hello dogbert - works on my local machine. not with the automated test.

Comment: Maybe the non-zero exit status is telling you that the script is legitimately failing for some reason. Are you sure the automated test will invoke it with an argument, the name of the file? Or will it expect your script to read from stdin? Or is the location of the interpreter (/usr/local/bin/ruby) different in the automated test? These are just guesses about what could go wrong.

Comment: Hello Rob, i'm not sure about these things either.. The submission guidelines on their website goes as follows: `You submissions are executed in a *NIX type environment. Assume softwares/shells etc are in their standard locations. Nothing else.`

Comment: Here's something interesting as well, this is in the Challenge itself. `The first argument is the pathname to a file which contains test data, one test case per line. Each line contains a positive integer. Each line is in the format: N i.e. a positive integer eg. `

Comment: My guess is that the test environment has no /usr/local/bin/ruby, so your script fails on the first line. You could try /usr/bin/ruby, but it really depends on the environment.

Comment: What online challenge? https://gist.github.com/1054098

Comment: `/usr/bin/env ruby` will use a *NIX environment path search to try to find ruby.  It is the better way, IMO.

Comment: @jonas: http://codeeval.com - I'm a student in college and i'm just looking forward to polish my programming skills. So, i thought i should start taking some programming challenges... @Ryanmt: I've just submitted my script with your suggested changes. I'm waiting for it to be analyzed.. I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: OK, i got it. They are using Ruby 1.8.6 to run the scripts. I wrote this in Ruby 1.9.2 and one of the methods: `count` i used in my script above was not available in 1.8.6. Hence, the script is failing. :(

Comment: You could try `(1..100).find_all{|o| o % 3 == 0}.length` instead of count.

Comment: By the way, `system(exit 0)` should be replaced by `exit 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if no exceptions arise during the execution of your script, or you don't exit with a certain code, the exit code of your application will be 0. I think this is standard for every programming language.

For example, to test this on Windows:

```
c:\> ruby my_script.rb
c:\> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

And on Unix systems:

```
$ ruby my_script.rb
$ echo $?
0
```

So, if no unexpected things can happen in your scripts, the problem is ( as you found out by yourself ) server-side.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SelfDescribe
    def check_desc str
        length = str.length - 1
        q = []
        str.each_char do |c|
            q << c
        end
        is_self_desc = 0
        for i in 0..length
            count = str.count(i.to_s)
            if(count == q[i].to_i)
                is_self_desc = 1
            else
                is_self_desc = 0
            end
        end
        is_self_desc
    end
    obj = SelfDescribe.new()
    file = ARGV[0]
    File.open("#{file}", 'r') do |f1|  
        while line = f1.gets  
            unless(line.eql?"\n")
                puts obj.check_desc(line.gsub(/[\n]+/, "") ) 
            end
        end  
    end
end
```

this code i wrote made a 100CE on the site . PS : while reading the integers line by line from the file they contain a carriage return at the end .eg 123 would be treated as '123\n' by ruby as line read are string.

**>  now we don't have to evaluate a blank line and also while checking a

> line we should strip /n off using .gsub(/[\n]+/, "") ...**

**So in ur case u can try using array.gsub(/[\n]+/, "")**